# How to create a basic camel project with mvn for eclipse (for dummies)?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-camel

as you can see I am quite a beginner using Camel. I am trying to create a very basic Eclipse project using Camel and Maven but somehow I always end up with errors and it simply doesn't seem to work. My example is very simple and I am not using Spring.

- I have tried copying folders from other projects and change the name but then maven doesn't like it and it doesn't let me run anything.
- I decided to start a new project from scratch with maven using:

  `mvn archetype:generate \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
    -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app \
    -DartifactId=my-app`
- Then tried creating a pom.xml myself, I even added the camel-core and the slf4j dependencies manually (check out my 40 lines of pom.xml at [HERE](http://pastebin.kde.org/p9pccinyf)), but I still cannot run it in eclipse and maven is not behaving any better. t
- Before attempting to run this example in eclipse I used the command "mvn eclipse:eclipse". But in Eclipse IDE I get the following error:

`log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.`

- The code I am trying to run is fairly simple as well, it is from an example I found in a book. You can check the very simple code sample [HERE](http://pastebin.kde.org/pybxkdebe).

I am completely lost, nothing I do seems to be able to work, and I still need to learn how to use Camel LoadBalancer using the failover construct. Can any one help me and tell me how to create a basic Camel project for dummies?

Thanks, Pedro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, you've already created a basic structure for your project. You've also added dependencies for camel & slf4j/log4j so you're almost good to go.

It is now time to configure the logging system before you can use it, as 
`log4j:WARN No appenders could be found` suggests. This and any other configuration problem should be explained in the links you also get in that error messages like [logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig). Follow those guidelines and you should be fine.

Also the guys at Apache have put up a decent FAQ and list of tutorials that you can check out [here](http://camel.apache.org/getting-started.html) [(this one is particularly related to log4j)](http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-log4j.html).

Comment: Your other command solved the entire problem because it had all the log4j defaults ready to go. Thanks !

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix could you please explain how you solved the problem?

Comment: @moldovean what's your issue? did you configure log4j?

Comment: I tried but I get the same error. I've created a log4j.xml and put it in the root of the module

Comment: @moldovean it's rarely supposed to be in the root of the project. If you're using maven, it's supposed to be in the `resources` folder.

Comment: @moldovean did that work for you? Also I'd appreciate some feedback from whoever down-voted my answer, about what's wrong with it or how it can be improved.

Comment: I downvoted it but not on purpose. i will get back to it, doing the examples now, when i have a working solution i will edit your answer and upvote

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144422/discussion-between-moldovean-and-morfic).